# How can I get two form fields side-by-side, with each field’s label above the field, in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on figuring out some css, I need a section of my form to look like the following,

[image: CSS float left]

I have tried every variation I can think of,

I have given the labels a fixed width and floated them left, then given the inputs the same width and floated them left.

I am all out of ideas, how can I achieve this please?

Comment: What does it currently look like? Plus post any code you may have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<form>
  <label for="company">
    <span>Company Name</span>
    <input type="text" id="company" />
  </label>
  <label for="contact">
    <span>Contact Name</span>
    <input type="text" id="contact" />
  </label>
</form>

label { width: 200px; float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; }
span { display: block; margin: 0 0 3px; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; }
input { width: 200px; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; }
```

Illustrated at http://jsfiddle.net/H3y8j/

Comment: This feels too much like a hack.

Comment: <span>s inside <label>s don't feel right to me. Nor do <input>s in <label>s, but that's probably why I'm biased. I'm not saying either is technically wrong. I guess you're just taking a way to do things that doesn't look clean and taking it a step further. It just doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do it in my opinion. But I respect that you may disagree.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation and I agree it's not perfectly clean but it achieves what the OP wanted in a clear and relatively semantic way. But a down vote?! Hardly not clear or useful when it was the accepted answer and you admit there's nothing technically wrong with it.

Comment: @TomDworzanski I think putting input and other things inside a label tag is not uncommon. It makes the entire area around the input and the label text clickable to focus the input. If you don't like this you can use div instead of label, and label instead of span. But I think it is fine and better the way that Scott did it.

Comment: What I am wondering is what to do if only one of the elements has a label, or if one of the labels is multiple lines. This would mess up the alignment. I do not currently know of a satisfactory solution for this. So I think I need to continue looking.

Comment: And btw what about display: block on the label as well?

Comment: And what about dynamic widths?

Answer (score 16):

You need an HTML element for each column in your layout.

I’d suggest:

#### HTML

```
<div class="two-col">
    <div class="col1">
        <label for="field1">Field One:</label>
        <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col2">
        <label for="field2">Field Two:</label>
        <input id="field2" name="field2" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.two-col {
    overflow: hidden;/* Makes this div contain its floats */
}

.two-col .col1,
.two-col .col2 {
    width: 49%;
}

.two-col .col1 {
    float: left;
}

.two-col .col2 {
    float: right;
}

.two-col label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Paul, put colon before 49%

Answer (score 5):

This works well

http://jsfiddle.net/aY9HC/

Comment: Except you should be using labels rather than divs:  http://jsfiddle.net/aY9HC/1/

Comment: @jlbruno: Oh, I didn't understand he meant `label` in the sense of the tag... I thought he was just referring at the titles as "labels".

Comment: it’s not really about him meaning the `label` tag, it’s the fact that the text is clearly labelling the form fields, and all form fields should have a human-readable label marked up as such. See http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html

Comment: Simple and best! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
<div id="leftContainer">
  <span>Company Name</span>
  <br><input type="text" value="John Lewis Partnership">
</div>
<div id="rightContainer">
  <span>Contact Name</span>
  <br><input type="text" value="Timothy Patten">
</div>
```

Then, you can align the 2 divs by floating them left and right:-

```
#leftContainer {
   float:left;
}

#rightContainer {
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but you’d want `<label>`s with `display: block;` rather than meaningless `<span>`s and a `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<div style="float:left; width:101px; height:auto;">
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">
        LabelText
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </div>
</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:101px; height:auto;">
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">
        LabelText
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </div>
</div>



</div>
```

Comment: You’d want actual `<label>` tags instead of `<div>`s, and there’s no need to float the labels as well.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me without css. I think css would put some icing on the cake though.

```
    <form>
        <label for="First Name" >First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlength="30" />
        <label for="Last Name" >Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlength="30" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
<style type="text/css">

form {width:400px;}

#text1 {float:right;}

#text2 {float:left;}

</style>
```

then

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">


 <label id="text1">Company Name<br />
   <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" />
 </label>

 <label id="text2">Contact Name<br />
   <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
 </label>


</form>
```

**Test Page:** http://jsbin.com/ahelo4

Works for me in the latest versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera. Not 100% sure about IE though as im on a Mac, but I cant see why it wouldn't :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to do it

```css
.style1 {display: inline-block;
                         }
```

```html
<form>
<div class="style1">
  <label for="field1">Company Name</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1">
  </div>
  <div class="style1">
  <label for="field2">Contact Name</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">
  </div>
</form>
```