# centering text labels above form fields side by side

Tags: text, center, label

I read [How can I get two form fields side-by-side, with each field’s label above the field, in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907275/how-can-i-get-two-form-fields-side-by-side-with-each-fields-label-above-the-fi) which seems to be close to what I need. Unfortunately, I am too new to this to understand most of it. My page used to work with tables, but somehow it got changed and mow it is based in form.

I can only center the labels with position:absolute but that seems to not work in smaller screens. Besides I wanted to use overflow:auto  and with the fixed labels it does not make sense when you scroll down the page. The autoflow is not so important, as the ability to keep things in place in smaller screens.

Any ideas that could help, please?

This is the page: http://pintotours.net/coding/form.php
An example for current code:

```
> <form method="post" action="./database.php">
>      <DIV style="position: absolute;  left:590px; width:40px; height:25px">Username</DIV> <DIV style="position: absolute; 
> right:545px; width:150px; height:25px">Repeat username</DIV> <br>
> 
>   <center>  <p><label for="Username"> </label><input type="text"
> name="username" />
>     <label for="Repeat Username"></label><input type="text" name="repeat-username" /></p>
> 
> <DIV style="position: absolute;  left:590px; width:40px;
> height:25px">Password</DIV> <DIV style="position: absolute; 
> right:557px; width:150px; height:25px">Repeat password</DIV> <br>
> 
>     <p><label for="Password"> </label><input type="text" name="password" />
>     <label for="Repeat Password"></label><input type="text" name="repeat-password" /></p><br>
>     
>     
>     </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tables for simple and speedy form design else use div with css property 'float:left'. Don't use  'absolute' and 'left' 'right' css properties. Check some other websites learn how they designed forms.

Comment: It's taken me so long to get this far, That I really would like to keep to current code, other than find a way to centre and FIX the labels. Isn't there a way? I have a css file but am at a loss what to put there. The two fields are in the centre of the page and I need to get the labels to sit on top of each field. Please, look at the webpage link that I left above.